# How do I install mercurial on ubuntu without X

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial

I want to install Mercurial on my Ubuntu server system, but I don't want X (this is a pure console system, no GUI at all). If I use `apt-get install mercurial` all the X libraries are pulled in. I know I can ignore them but I want to keep my system minimal - is there a way of installing `hg` *without* any GUI tools?

Comment: Pulling in the X libraries isn't the same as pulling in the X tools. If you really want to install with out X libraries, you'll probably need to recompile yourself.

Comment: Hmm, I'd assumed that the X stuff was only needed for one of the extensions - and so there might be a "core Mercurial" package that didn't include those extensions and didn't require X. If not, fair enough. It's only a minor VM image bloat, I guess...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

X is pulled in due to Wish (Tcl/Tk shell).

We can use:
`$ sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install mercurial`

Source:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/458614/why-does-package-mercurial-depend-on-x11-common-in-a-chrooted-environment

Answer (score 3):

You can always install it manually, behind the back of the package manager, without installing the dependency on X.  The command-line portion of Mercurial doesn't depend on much of anything, beyond a working Python install of a recent 2.x vintage (say, 2.7).

FYI, to see what the latest released version is, visit https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads.

The version there now is "mercurial-3.0-rc".  The "rc" is a "release candidate", which might be too bleeding-edge for you.  You can browse the list of all releases at: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/.  At the time of this writing, the most recent release is Mercurial 2.9.2.  So I'll show you how to install that.

Steps to install:

First, download the "source release" of Mercurial 2.9.2 with this curl command:

> ```
> curl -C - -O https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/mercurial-2.9.2.tar.gz
> ```

Untar with this command:

> ```
> tar -xzf mercurial-2.9.2.tar.gz
> ```

Build & install with these commands:

> ```
> cd mercurial-2.9.2
> sudo python setup.py install
> ```

You're done!  Verify that it is installed:

> ```
> which hg
> hg --version
> ```

Comment: Looks like this is the best answer, as there's no non-X version of the package on my OS.